# Why does the method reference I am passing to Arrays.sort need to be static?

Tags: java, methods, java-8

I am new bie to Java 8. I am trying to create a sample for Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type.

I have a person class with one field Name and trying to sort Array of Person objects on firstName field of person class.

```
public class Person{

    String firstName;

    public Person(String firstName) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public int compareByFirstName(Person p1, Person p2) {
        return p1.getFirstName().compareTo(p2.getFirstName());
    }

}

public class TestInstanceMethorRefArbObjSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestInstanceMethorRefArbObjSample obj=new TestInstanceMethorRefArbObjSample();
        obj.personSorting();
    }

    private void personSorting() {
        Person[] personArr= {new Person("Jinesh"),new Person("Sejal"),new Person("Ashish")};
        Arrays.sort(personArr,Person::compareByFirstName);
    }
}
```

But I am facing compilation issue on below line.

```
Arrays.sort(personArr,Person::compareByFirstName);
```

> 1.The type Person does not define compareByFirstName(T, T) that is applicable
>   here  TestInstanceMethorRefArbObjSample.java  /InstaceMethodArbitaryObjectProject/src/com/methodreference/instancemethodrefarbitary/client    line
>   11    Java Problem
>   2.The type Person does not define compareByFirstName(T, T) that is applicable
>   here  TestInstanceMethorRefArbObjSample.java  /InstaceMethodArbitaryObjectProject/src/com/methodreference/instancemethodrefarbitary/client    line
>   11    Java Problem

I am just trying to pass the implementation of int compare(T o1, T o2); using compareByFirstname of Person class.

As soon as I am changing the method compareByFirstname of Person class  to static everything is working fine.

**Why I need to change the compareByFirstname to static method to make it work?**

Comment: Because without static, Your method is an instance method, and you would thus need 3 Person objects to call it: the receiver (i.e. this), p1, and p2. A Comparator is a function taking 2 Persons, not 3. Remove the p1 argument, and compare `this` with p2, and it will work as expected.

Comment: `compareByFirstName` is not static.

Comment: [Array.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) method definition requires a `Comparator` instance as its second argument.

Comment: @JBNiZet Thank you for explanation ! .one question from my side why below code works as String[] stringArray = { "Barbara", "James", "Mary", "John", "Patricia", "Robert", "Michael", "Linda" };
Arrays.sort(stringArray, String::compareToIgnoreCase); I dont see compareToIgoreCase is defined as static method.

Comment: Well, read my comment again. compareToIgnoreCase doesn't take 2 arguments as your method does. It takes one. And it thus compares `this` with another String. It's thus acceptable as a Comparator, since it's a function taking two Strings: the receiver String, and the String passed as argument.

Comment: @JBNIzet Apologies from my side. I got the idea now. Thanks once again!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Some background**

`Arrays.sort` expects a `Comparator`, which, when passing a *method reference*, must be a method that accepts two instances of the appropriate type.

There are two ways to create such a method:

1. Create a *static* method in *any* class that accepts *two* parameters of the appropriate type. This is essentially what you have done. Such a method does not need to be declared in the specific class, you could also have some other class that provides such helper methods.

Your compiler will make sure that the generated `Comparator` instance calls the referenced method with the 2 instances it wants to compare.

2. Create an *instance* method in *the specific class for that type* that accepts *one* parameter of the appropriate type.

Your compiler will make sure that the generated `Comparator` instance calls the referenced method on the 1st instance with the 2nd instance as parameter.

**Your specific case**

Since your method takes *two* parameters, it must be static, as it otherwise needs a *third* instance to run. Either declare it static, or remove one parameter and implement the comparison between *this* and the parameter.

Comment: @Thanks JBNizet and MaxVollmer for explanation in detailed manner.

Comment: Just for completeness: it can also be a non-static method taking two parameters, with the reference taken from an instance, like `personInstance::compareByFirstName`

Comment: But the preferred way is to use `Comparator.comparing(Person::getFirstName)` which eliminates the need for an extra comparison method completely.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a method reference and since you have written it as `Person::compareByFirstName` it is referencing a static method. If you wanted to reference an instance method instead you would need to first create an instance of the object, then you would reference the method with the instance, like so:

```
Person p = new Person("");
p::compareByFirstName
```

However this would not be what you want to do in your case as the compare method is not instance-specific.

You could change your comparison method to make it specific to the instance by comparing the object instance with another object

```
public int compareByFirstName(Person p2) {
    return this.getFirstName().compareTo(p2.getFirstName());
}
```

In which case you would be able to use the method reference `Person::compareByFirstName` as the comparison becomes arbitary.

Comment: "*and since you have written it as `Person::compareByFirstName` it is referencing a static method*" no, construct `ClassName::method` is **not** reserved only for static methods. If we have `SomeFunctionalInterface` which contains method like `handle(SomeClass sc, Foo f, Bar b)` then we can provide `ClassName::nonStaticMethod` as its implementation. It would be similar to implementing it with lambda `(SomeClass sc, Foo f, Bar b) -> sc.nonStaticMethod(f, b);`. So first argument will be treated as instance on which `nonStaticMethod` will be invoked.